# seperate custom and vendor assets laravel structure

Tags: laravel, directory-structure

Usually if I work in a basic php project, I seperate my custom and vendor assets like this:

> - assets (folder)
>
>   - css (folder)
>
>     - home.css
>   - js (folder)
>
>     - dashboard.js
>   - vendor (folder)
>
>     - bootstrap (folder)
>
>       - css (folder)
>
>         - bootstrap.min.css
>       - js (folder)
>
>         - bootstrap.min.js

I have alot of vendors to use like charts, codemirror, clipboard, etc. But, I'm confused how can I apply this in Laravel. Because we already have vendor folder in Laravel. So, I don't know where should I put my custom and vendor assets. Please help me.

Comment: I think it makes sense to keep both in the vendor folder, it describes it fine. But also wouldn't be wrong to make another folder with any other name.

Answer (score 0):

You could shove everything in the public folder. the `asset()` helper places you in the public folder by default, so in your blade files you could have something like

```xml
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
```